How to upload multiple images through Wordpress REST API from FLutter APP
I'm learning Flutter application development and I have been faced with a major issue of how to save multiple files uploaded from the phone to the WordPress website through rest API. I have captured the files through Flutter as shown by the following code.
 void saveCheckIn() async {
        if (_image.length > 6) {
          Toasts.show("Upload a max of 6 IMAGES");
          return;
        }
        final formData = FormData.fromMap({
          'name': 'dio',
          'date': DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
        });
    
        for (var imageFile in _image) {
          formData.files.addAll([
            MapEntry("images[]", await MultipartFile.fromFile(imageFile.path)),
          ]);
        }
    
        Dio dio = Dio();
    
        dynamic headers = {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Content-type": "application/json"
        };
    
        try {
          BuildContext showDialogContext = Toasts.showLoading(context: context);
          var response = await dio.post(
            "${Constants.baseUrl}/clients/checkin",
            options: Options(
              headers: headers,
            ),
            data: formData,
          );
          Navigator.of(showDialogContext).pop();
          print(response.data.toString());
        } catch (e) {
          Toasts.show("Error: $e");
        }
      }

From the above dart code, _image is a List containing all the image files
I'm not sure how to receive those images through WordPress REST API. I have tried to do research but I can't find anything helpful. This is my WordPress Code
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'wpmam_rest_user_endpoints' );
function wpmam_rest_user_endpoints( $request ){
    
    register_rest_route(
        'wp-mobile-app-manager/v2',
        "clients/checkin",
        array(
            "methods" => array( "POST", "GET", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH" ),
            "callback" => "wpmam_mobile_app_checkin_clients"
        )
    );
}

function wpmam_mobile_app_checkin_clients($request){
    $response = array();
    $parameters = $request->get_json_params();

    $username = $parameters['username'];
    $password = $parameters['password'];
    $name = $parameters['name'];
    $date = $parameters['date'];
    $images = $parameters['files']['images']; // NOT SURE IF THIS IS CORRECT

    foreach ($images as $key => $value) {
        // NOT SURE HOW TO MOVE ON
    }


    wpmap_upload_files( $request = null, $user_id = 0 );

    return new WP_REST_Response( $response, 123 );
}


to put files in wordpress media library, you can use this wordpress function : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_upload/
